Type narrowing on an object array
I have this code:
const f = (x: unknown) => {
  if (!x || !Array.isArray(x)) {
    throw new Error("bad");
  }

  for (const y of x) {
    if (!y || typeof y !== "object") {
      throw new Error("bad");
    }

    y // y does intellisense think this has type `any`
  }
};

In my VS Code, intellisense thinks the final y has type any. I would expect it to have type object. Why is this? And how should I structure my code so that intellisense recognizes the second y has type object?

Looks like you've run into a combination of ms/TS#43865 and ms/TS#54239, and you need to work around at least one of them, such as by assigning any[] to unknown[] as shown in this playground link. If that fully addresses the question I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

https://www.totaltypescript.com/ts-reset promises to fix this

@jcalz yes, that fully answers my question. Thank you!

I will write an answer when I get a chance, probably in about 8 hours (it's my bedtime now)

This is a combination of two issues.
The first issue is described at microsoft/TypeScript#43865. The Array.isArray() method currently acts as a type guard function that narrows its input to any[]. This is fairly reasonable behavior but there are a lot of edge cases where it doesn't do what people want.  The element type is the intentionally unsafe any type, and that means as soon as you access elements, they will be of type any.  In your case, the more desirable behavior would be if it narrowed to unknown[] instead, where the elements are of the type-safe unknown type.
The second issue is described at microsoft/TypeScript#54239. Certain type guard operations, such as truthiness narrowing, simply don't work on values of type any.  Presumably truthiness checking on any should narrow to at least {}, and then typeof being "object" would narrow to object. But that doesn't happen, unfortunately. This does happen for unknown, though.
That's why it's happening.

To proceed, you'll need to work around at least one of those two issues. There are countless ways to do this (you could always just give up assert y as object at the bottom of the code) but I'd probably recommend one of these:
To work around the Array.isArray() check yielding any[], you could reassign the resulting any[] to unknown[], as shown here:
const f = (x: unknown) => {
  if (!x || !Array.isArray(x)) {
    throw new Error("bad");
  }
  for (const y of x satisfies unknown[] as unknown[]) {
    if (!y || typeof y !== "object") {
      throw new Error("bad");
    }
    ((y))
    //^? const y: object
  }
};

By writing x satisfies unknown[] as unknown[] I'm using the satisfies operator to make sure TypeScript is okay with assigning x to unknown[] (so you'd get an error if you, say, change the !Array.isArray(x) test to Array.isArray(x)), and then I'm using the as type assertion operator to treat x as unknown[].  (You could do this without satisfies, but then you might not get an error if x is not assignable to unknown[]. Then the for (const y of x will see y as type unknown, and the rest of the code works because that's narrowable to object.
Similarly you could just use a new variable like
const f = (x: unknown) => {
  if (!x || !Array.isArray(x)) {
    throw new Error("bad");
  }
  const _x: unknown[] = x;
  for (const y of _x) {
    if (!y || typeof y !== "object") {
      throw new Error("bad");
    }
    ((y))
    //^? const y: object
  }
};


Or you could leave the Array.isArray() check alone and work around the narrowing of y from any to object by writing your own type guard function for narrowing arbitrary values to object:
function isObject(z: unknown) {
  return !!z && typeof z === "object"
}

Here isObject is inferred to be a type predicate function of the form (z: unknown) => z is object (but if you use an older version of TypeScript you might need to annotate the return type yourself).  And now you can just use isObject() in place of your inline check:
const f = (x: unknown) => {
  if (!x || !Array.isArray(x)) {
    throw new Error("bad");
  }
  for (const y of x) {
    if (!isObject(y)) {
      throw new Error("bad");
    }
    ((y))
    //^? const y: object
  }
};

Looks good.
Playground link to code

y is an array item, and its type isn't specified, so TypeScript infers it as any. Consider using Generic Types to ensure type safety and to perform operations based on the input type..
function f<T>(x: T[]) {
  if (!x || !Array.isArray(x)) {
    throw new Error('bad');
  }

  for (const y of x) {
    if (!y || typeof y !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('bad');
    }

    y; // y does intellisense think this has type `any`
  }
}

f([1, 2, 4]);

The function type of the above function call will infer function f<number>(x: number[]): void automatically since you are passing the numbers.

f() is intended to accept unknown input, though. If you're willing to require f() accept only arrays, why not just write function f(x: object[]) {} and then not check anything inside?  This answer seems to miss the point of the question, and it's not clear how generics does anything useful here.

// because x: unknown
// Case 1: array object => typeof y === 'object'
f( [{ "key": "value" }] )
// Case 2: array string => typeof y === 'string'
f( ['a'] )

Please [edit] to write in words what you think the code in your answer is demonstrating. OP knows that if you call f(['a']) then y will not be an object, but then a runtime error will be thrown. If code flow reaches the commented line, y should definitely be an object, right? Then OP's question is why hasn't it been narrowed to object?  This answer doesn't seem to address that at all.
